# How to hide NavigationView ? android:visibility="gone" is not working

Tags: android

I am using 2 ( Left and Right ) NavigationView for my app, and want to show right NavigationView for certain conditions only. Hence set its visibility to "GONE" in layout file and will make it visible when it is needed. However even after making it "GONE" right NavigationView keep showing up.

Any thoughts how to hide it ?

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.example.girishkhatri.tt0401.NavigationViewRight
    android:id="@+id/nav_right_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:visibility="gone"    //not working as expected 
   app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_selector"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_right"
     app:menu="@menu/activity_right_drawer" />
```

Comment: Add `gravity` attribute to right ... it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent the user from opening the drawer and you want to show it in special circumstance, it's better to use `lock` and `unlock` for the drawer.

Put a listener for the drawer and in its `OnDrawerClosed`, Lock it again.

Whenever you should show the drawer, unlock it first and then call open on it

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I locked NavigationView in NavigationDrawer itself and unlocked for activity where it is needed..

Answer (score 7):

Never opened NavigationView with the following code.

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

---

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

Comment: Thanks Tsuyoshi Hiraga, it's workig fine.

 for lock drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)


for unlock drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNDEFINED)

Answer (score 0):

Please try, layout_gravity="end".

Comment: layout_gravity specifies from where will navigationview appear.